# Corona sdk physics precise collision between 2 round objects

Tags: android, sdk, physics, coronasdk

I am working on the start of a golf game where a ball rolls into a hole. I have it working, but when the ball simply touches the edge of the hole, the collision event makes it drop in (disappear). I want to create more precision so that it will be more realistic. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start a [transition](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/animation) when you detect the collision with the hole.  That transition would take some time to complete, eliminating your "ball immediately disappears" problem, and with a little math, could properly reflect the speed and direction of the ball so that the drop into the hole looks fairly realistic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is have the real body be an invisible ball smaller than display ball that the user sees.  You can also manipulate the pre and post collision event handlers to deal with this.

You also should be wary of the fact that speed matters in Box2d collisions. This kind of mechanic often takes some tweaking in my experience.

http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection

Comment: You would only want to use that body for the hole collision, it wouldn't make sense for the ball to go partially inside the wall before bouncing.

Comment: Actually, I want the ball to fall into the hole, which it is doing (sort of) It disappears when it collides with the hole. My problem is that it disappears when it barely touches the hole. I'm thinking about comparing the x, y of the ball with the x, y of the hole when a collision occurs, and keep it visible if the comparison is not close. My problem at this point is that I am new to lua. Thanks for the answers. I am appreciative.

Comment: I now understand my problem a little better. I am trying to detect a precise colision between a round body and a round sensor. The round body (ball) disappears when it even grazes the sensor (hole). Is there a way to make it a little more realistic like a golf ball and hole? Thanks for any advice.